# How to get user's info only using user's ID? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So far I just wanted to get user's info using their discord ID, I know I can use `discord.Member` instead, but I want to do it with their ID and do like `k!userinfo 326024842765664257`

Is there any way?

Here is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
@client.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member.id):
    embedinfo = discord.Embed()
    embedinfo.set_author(name=f"User info: {member}")
    embedinfo.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embedinfo.add_field(name="Guild Name:", value=member.display_name)
    embedinfo.add_field(name="Created on:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
    embedinfo.add_field(name="Joined on:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
    embedinfo.set_footer(text=f"Request by: {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedinfo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you had with [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) will work fine with the ID. The argument will return a `discord.Member` object based off of whether you give a viable attribute (such as the ID. Also, this means you don't need to bother with using a [`Client.get_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) or [`Guild.get_member()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member).

Additionally, if you use this method, it won't need to be re-coded at a later date if you change your mind about how you want to get the member. You can also get the ID from the Member object if you so desire.

## Code:

```py
@client.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    memb_id = member.id
    embedinfo = discord.Embed()
    embedinfo.set_author(name=f"User info: {member.username}#{member.discriminator}") # changed from {member}
    embedinfo.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embedinfo.add_field(name="Guild Name:", value=member.display_name)
    embedinfo.add_field(name="Created on:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
    embedinfo.add_field(name="Joined on:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
    embedinfo.set_footer(text=f"Request by: {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedinfo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Client.get_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user).

```
@client.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, member_id: discord.Member.id):
    member = client.get_user(member_id)
    embedinfo = discord.Embed()
    embedinfo.set_author(name=f"User info: {member}")
    embedinfo.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embedinfo.add_field(name="Guild Name:", value=member.display_name)
    embedinfo.add_field(name="Created on:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
    embedinfo.add_field(name="Joined on:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
    embedinfo.set_footer(text=f"Request by: {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedinfo)
```